# How to add checkbox using hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()

Tags: forms

Running Drupal 9 with paragraphs module, paragraphs collapsible and paragraphs jquery ui accordion installed.  I wish to modify paragraphs' form, specifically where it displays private files by adding a 'Switch to Public' checkbox under each file description (see attached image).

I am using hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().  Here is example code:

```
**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().
 */

 function sbn_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
     if (!empty($element['subform']['field_private_files'])) {
         
#       $element['subform']['field_private_files']['widget'][0]['#default_value']['switch'] = [
#             '#type'          => 'checkbox',
#             '#title'         => t('Switch to Public'),
#             '#required'      => FALSE,
#             '#default_value' => FALSE,
#           ];

     $element['subform']['field_private_files']['widget'][0]['#default_value']['switch'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => t('Switch to public'),
        '#size' => 10,
        '#maxlength' => 255,
        '#default_value' => 1,
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#description' => '<p>' . t('Switch from private to public.') . '</p>',
    );
 
        // dsm($element);
     }
}
```

I know the array elements are there because I used dsm to print out the entire form if ['subform']['field_private_files'] exists:

```
   [field_private_files] => Array
        (
            [#type] => container
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field_body1
                    [1] => 7
                    [2] => subform
                    [3] => field_body2
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => subform
                    [6] => field_private_files_wrapper
                )

            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => field--type-file
                            [1] => field--name-field-private-files
                            [2] => field--widget-file-generic
                            [3] => paragraphs-content
                        )

                )

            [widget] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [#title] => Private Files
                            [#description] => 
                            [#field_parents] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => field_body1
                                    [1] => 7
                                    [2] => subform
                                    [3] => field_body2
                                    [4] => 0
                                    [5] => subform
                                )

                            [#required] => 
                            [#delta] => 0
                            [#weight] => 0
                            [#type] => managed_file
                            [#upload_location] => private://
                            [#upload_validators] => Array
                                (
                                    [file_validate_size] => Array(1)
                                    [file_validate_extensions] => Array(1)
                                )

                            [#value_callback] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\FileWidget
                                    [1] => value
                                )

                            [#process] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array(2)
                                    [1] => Array(2)
                                )

                            [#progress_indicator] => throbber
                            [#extended] => 1
                            [#field_name] => field_private_files
                            [#entity_type] => paragraph
                            [#display_field] => 1
                            [#display_default] => 1
                            [#description_field] => 1
                            [#cardinality] => -1
                            [#default_value] => Array
                                (
                                    [target_id] => 436
                                    [display] => 1
                                    [description] => Executive Session Minutes 11-15-21
                                    [fids] => Array(1)
                                )
```

Any suggestions on how to code this so a checkbox would be printed under the 'description' of each Private Files section of each paragraph (there could be multiple paragraphs attached to each node).  Thanks!

Comment: This should be done with a field widget for the Private Files field, not through the paragraph's form.

Comment: Can you point to an example of what you mean?  It took me forever just to figure out how to use the hook with paragraphs!  Not a lot of documentation on how to use out there.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-field-widget